# wpa_supplicant: connect to WLAN in the background (during boot)

Tags: linux, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I am using manual configuration to connect to my WLAN. In my wpa_supplicant.conf, I have something like this:

```
network={
    ssid="mywifi"
    key_management=WPA-EAP
    ...
}
```

and then, in my `/etc/network/interfaces` I have

```
auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
```

When I start my laptop, the connection to my WLAN is established automatically. The problem is, it takes sometimes 10 - 15 seconds until the connection is established and the whole boot process is blocked and waiting.

I was wondering whether it is possible to configure, so that the connection is established in the background, so that the boot process can go on booting, without waiting for the WLAN to be ready.

I am using Debian Wheezy

Comment: The hard way you could trace with `find` and `grep` your initialization scripts looking for `ifconfig` or `ifup` calls and put an ampersand glyph in the call that is blocking you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably your dhcp client blocking until it the interface has an address.  The exact answer will depend on what init system you use and what dhcp client you use.  For `dhcpcd`, for example, you want to make sure the init script that launches it is called with the `-b` flag (background immediately), and if it has the `-w` flag (wait), to erase it.

One caveat is that if you have services starting after this interface is launched that depend on it having an IP address, this could cause problems if they start in the few seconds before an IP is secured.  Keep that in mind if you encounter any oddities.

Comment: I am using `dhclient`, but since my wlan interface is started automatically during boot (by init scripts) I don't know how to modify the parameters with which it is being run

Comment: If you use svsV init or OpenRC the init script is in `/etc/init.d` and would be called dhclient or dhcp or dhcpcd depending on distro. If you use systemd init it might be under /etc/systemd and have a name like dhclient@wlan0.